# setting values of np.array based on the values of another np.array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I have a numpy array A, which contains values between 0 and 1. I want to create another numpy array y, such that the value of y(i) = 1 if A(i) >= 0.5, and y(i) = 0 if A(i) < 0.5. I used the following python code:

```
f=lambda v: 1 if v>0.5 else 0  
vf=np.vectorize(f)  
Y=vf(A)
```

Is there a way to do this function in one line command instead of three lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy

A = numpy.random.rand(10)
print(A)
```

Array **A**:

```
[ 0.76702953  0.89697124  0.54573644  0.48079479  0.39556016  0.50646642
  0.45998033  0.11159339  0.69824144  0.37451713]
```

---

Create another numpy array `y`, such that the value of `y(i) = 1` if `A(i) >= 0.5`, and `y(i) = 0` if `A(i) < 0.5`.

```
Y = (A >= 0.5).astype(int)
print(Y)
```

Array **Y**:

```
[1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a vectorized comparison and cast the result to int:

```
(A >= 0.5).astype(int)
```

`A >= 0.5` produces an array of elementwise `>= 0.5` comparison results, and `astype(int)` casts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`.

If you can live with single byte integers

```
(A >= 0.5).view(np.int8)
```

is a bit faster. Unlike `astype` `view` does not create new data. It reinterprets the data buffer of its operand